# How do I flip the Y-axis so the (0,0) ends up in the Bottom-left corner

Tags: java, android, libgdx

My Y-axis is flip so it's in the top left corners, but this problem only occurs with the

```
bounds = new Rectangle()
```

I am using the `OrthographicCamera` like this

```
camera= new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

My question is, how do I flip the Y-axis so the (0,0) ends up in the Bottom-left corner

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Player player;
    Player2 player2;
    InputProcessor inputprocessor;
    Texture img;
    Vector2 pos;
    Rectangle bounds;
    GameTime gameTime;
    ShapeRenderer sr;

    Rectangle p1,p2,p3,p4;
    Rectangle tSwitch;

    Rectangle Bplayer;

    Vector2 p;
    Vector2 button1,button2,button3,button4;
    Vector2 tButton;

    BitmapFont font;

    OrthographicCamera camera;

    int xi = 0;
    int yi = 0;

    int Movetime = 0;

    int playerSwitch = 0;

    float totalTime = 3*60;

    Rectangle touchPos;

    @Override
    public void create () {

        camera= new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        player = new Player(new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 , Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2),"badlogic.jpg");
        player2 = new Player2(new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 , Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2),"Fagot.jpg");
        pos = new Vector2(player.getPosition().x,player.getPosition().y);
        gameTime = new GameTime();

        button1 = new Vector2(0,0);
        button2 = new Vector2(200,0);
        button3 = new Vector2(1620,0);
        button4 = new Vector2(1820,0);

        tButton = new Vector2(800,0);

        p1 = new Rectangle(button1.x + 100,button1.y+1225,100,100);
        p2 = new Rectangle(button2.x + 100,button2.y+1225,100,100);
        p3 = new Rectangle(button3.x + 100,button3.y+1225,100,100);
        p4 = new Rectangle(button4.x + 100,button4.y+1225,100,100);

        Bplayer = new Rectangle(player2.getPosition().x,player2.getPosition().y,100,100);

        tSwitch = new Rectangle(tButton.x+100, tButton.y+1225 ,100,100);

        sr = new ShapeRenderer();

        font = new BitmapFont();

        player.getPosition().x = 100;
        player.getPosition().y = 100;

        player2.setPosition(new Vector2(500, 500));


        bounds = new Rectangle(player.getPosition().x   , player.getPosition().y  , 255, 255);
        touchPos = new Rectangle(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(),200,200);


    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update(false);

        bounds.setPosition(player.getPosition().x,player.getPosition().y);

        //bounds = new Rectangle(player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y + 800, 255, 255);

        float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();
        totalTime -= deltaTime;

        String time = String.valueOf(totalTime);

        String meow = String.valueOf(playerSwitch);

        String Mtime = String.valueOf(Movetime);

        batch.begin();
        font.draw(batch, meow, 500, 500);
        batch.end();

        if(Gdx.input.isTouched(1)){
            xi = Gdx.input.getX();
            yi = Gdx.input.getY();
        }

        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            Vector3 pointerPos = new Vector3();
            pointerPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            touchPos.x = pointerPos.x /*+ 64 / 2*/;
            touchPos.y = pointerPos.y /* + 64 / 2*/;
        }


        if(touchPos.overlaps(tSwitch)&& Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            playerSwitch++;


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        //}else if(touchPos.overlaps(tSwitch)&& Gdx.input.isTouched() ){
        //  playerSwitch=1;
        }

        if(touchPos.overlaps(bounds)&& Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            batch.begin();
            font.draw(batch,"K",900,1000);
            batch.end();
        }




        if(playerSwitch == 1){

        if(touchPos.overlaps(p1)&& Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            player.getPosition().x += 5f;
            Movetime++;
        }
        if(touchPos.overlaps(p2)&& Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            player.getPosition().y += 5f;
            Movetime++;
        }
        if(touchPos.overlaps(p3)&& Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            player.getPosition().x -= 5f;
            Movetime++;
        }
        if(touchPos.overlaps(p4)&& Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            player.getPosition().y -= 5f;
            Movetime++;
        }

        }

        if(playerSwitch == 2){

            if(touchPos.overlaps(p1)&& Gdx.input.isTouched()){
                player2.getPosition().x += 5f;
            }
            if(touchPos.overlaps(p2)&& Gdx.input.isTouched()){
                player2.getPosition().y += 5f;
            }
            if(touchPos.overlaps(p3)&& Gdx.input.isTouched()){
                player2.getPosition().x -= 5f;
            }
            if(touchPos.overlaps(p4)&& Gdx.input.isTouched()){
                player2.getPosition().y -= 5f;
            }

            }

        //Draw method
        font.setScale(5, 5);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(player.getTexture(), player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y);
        batch.draw(player2.getTexture(),player2.getPosition().x, player2.getPosition().y);
        font.draw(batch, time, 900, 1100);
        font.draw(batch, meow, 500, 500);
        font.draw(batch, Mtime, 200,200 );
        batch.end();

        sr.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        sr.setColor(255,255,255,255);
        sr.rect(player.getPosition().x , player.getPosition().y, 255, 255);
        sr.rect(player2.getPosition().x, player2.getPosition().y, 200, 200);
        sr.end();

    }

}
```

Comment: How are you using the rectangle? A Rectangle in libgdx doesn't specify which direction it goes, so the problem lies in how you are converting it into something to draw. Need to see more code.

Comment: So now the code is embedded. What i am trying to do is making a hit box for a player. @Tenfour04

Comment: You didn't show how you get `touchPos`, but I think that's probably your issue. Touch coordinates come into libgdx with y-down. You should use `camera.unproject` to convert touch coordinates into game coordinates before you use them.

Comment: So it's in the middle now  @Tenfour04

Comment: What's "it"? Middle of what?